# Dynamic roles list in CustomAuthorize ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, razor, asp.net-identity, roles

In

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles="Editor, Admin, Manager")]
```

1. How can I use a variable / array of roles in static string
   `Roles="Editor, Admin, Manager"` ?
2. How can I put a string variable or even n `list<string>` of CSV into
   the roles?

How to get rolesList into roles for customAttribute

```
  List<string> rolesList = new List<string>();
    rolesList.add("Editor").add("Admin").add("Manager");
    //...
    // now get that list
    [CustomAuthorize(Roles= `"` + string.Join<string>(",", rolesList) + `"` )]
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, no.  You can't.  Attributes are static metadata compiled into your application, and thus cannot be updated at runtime.

The longer answer is that if you really need this functionality, you'll have to implement your own Authorize attribute.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, was wondering where I was getting the errors from! Can you clue me on how I could go about this... is there a nuget pacakge out there... I dont to be compiling on every page view... just at app start, and login.